# Captcha Non PHP

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, captcha

Does anyone know of any good solutions to implement CAPTCHA on a form that cannot use php?

I am able to use PHP but only in an external file.
Javascript anywhere

Comment: Instead of saying what you can't use, it might also be helpful to list what you can use!

Comment: Good spot, makes sense, I have added this info to the post above

Comment: A Javascript CAPTCHA would be about as effective as leaving your car doors unlocked and windows rolled down in a bad neighborhood relying only on a small sign in the windshield saying "please do not vandalize."  Most bots don't even understand Javascript, and you are not going to be able to make an effective defense against them without *some variety of server-side validation*.

Answer (score 3):

Use [reCAPTCHA](http://www.google.com/recaptcha). You can validate it using almost any programming language that can access a web service - so every language that contains some way to make network connections.

Comment: I've heard a lot of bad reviews from this service, plus I want to control my own script not rely on a remote system

Comment: If you write something own chances are good that it sucks either for your users or for you: i.e. it'll be too hard and annoy users or too easy and annoy you as bots will be able to circumvent it. Besides that: do you really want to implement a voice captcha for those who cannot view images (yes, there are quite a few blind people on the internet!)

Comment: I prefer the flexibility of a homebrew solution. I don't need this to be bullet proof just something simple. I understand your concerns and thank you for raising them. I enjoy building my own solutions.

Answer (score 1):

Are you able to have an external (in the folder, but not affiliated with the form you're trying to use) PHP file, or does it have to be completely PHP-free?

Because I was going to suggest just doing a POST request to that file using JS.

Comment: Yes this would be possible. I need an example ideally though